# Stop loss and take profit always triggered on candle after the entry candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The intention of the script:

Short - go short from the top of Bollinger Bands with take profit at the middle basis line and stop loss at trade entry price + (10*ATR)

Long - go long from the bottom of the Bollinger Bands with a take profit at the middle basis line and stop loss at trade entry price - (10*ATR)

The stop losses are wide to show the issue that the SL isn't being triggered at the level set.

The entry signals are working. But the the take profit and stop loss levels are being triggered on the next candle rather than when the take profit or stop loss are hit.

Please could someone help me debug so that the take profit and stop loss work correctly.

The script is being run on Wall Street Daily with Spreadex.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Kalozo

//@version=5

strategy(shorttitle="BB Triple MA", title="Bollinger Bands plus Triple MA", overlay=true)
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
maType = input.string("SMA", "Basis MA Type", options = ["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")

ma(source, length, _type) =>
    switch _type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

//Calculate the Bollinger Bands

basis = ma(src, length, maType)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)

//Calculate the triple MA indicator
ma = 2
average1 = ta.sma(close,ma)
average2 = ta.sma(average1,ma)
average3 = ta.sma(average2,ma)

//Calculate the ATR
atr=ta.atr(10)

//Calculate stop losses
entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
UpperStopLoss = entry_price + (atr * 10)
LowerStopLoss = entry_price - (atr * 10)

//Calculate the buy and sell signals
buysignal = (close[1] <= lower[1]) and close > average3 and close[1] < average3[1] and upper-lower > 2 * atr
sellsignal = (close[1] >= upper[1]) and close < average3 and close[1] > average3[1] and upper-lower > 2 * atr


//Enter the buy trade
if buysignal
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty =1)

//Manage the buy TP and SL
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("Exit Long Basis",from_entry = "Long", stop = UpperStopLoss, limit = basis, qty =1)

//Enter the sell trade
if sellsignal
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short, qty = 1)

//Manage the sell TP and SL
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.exit("Exit Short Basis", from_entry = "Short", stop = LowerStopLoss, limit = basis, qty =1)

//Plot indicators 
plot(average3, color = close > average3  ? color.green : color.red, linewidth = 3)
plot(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))type here
```